# Prevent SwiftUI App from going to sleep op WatchOS

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I'm trying to record some CoreMotion data from a watch app I'm making. Every time I go to move, however, the app goes inactive after a while. Since this app is more for testing purposes, I'd like to keep it active as long as it's recording data.

I think I'm basically looking for the SwiftUI equivalent on WatchOS of `UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`.

Comment: As you can see in your own code, `isIdleTimerDisabled` is `UIApplication`'s property and there is no equivalent in `WatchKit`. I think you should try using workout mode to prevent sleep.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @MohammadRahchamani. I will try using workout mode.